# How to use UIHint in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Can I use UIHint in Silverlight ?

How would I use it?

Answer (score 0):

At least for the `DataForm`, `UIHint` cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to use UIHint in Silverlight using a third party package. https://github.com/teyc/Silverlight-Toolkit.DataForm.UIHint

In your `DataForm` add the attribute:

```
<toolkit:DataForm
    xmlns:please="clr-namespace:Silverlight.DataForm.UIHint;assembly=Silverlight.DataForm.UIHint"
    please:Use.UiHint="true" />
```

Natively the package supports UIHints for displaying combo boxes. You'll have to extend it yourself to support other UIHints